# Image source not updating in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'd like to have a button updating its content's image source when i modify the status.

XAML:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PlayerStartups}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding PlayerStartups.Count}" Margin="10"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PlayerStartupStatusProvider}}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"
                              x:Name="DataTemplateComboBox"
                              Margin="5" Grid.Column="0">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate ... />
                    </ComboBox>
                    <Button Margin="5" Grid.Column="1"
                            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.SetPlayerPropertiesCommand, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding TokenSource}" 
                               Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

`PlayerStartups` is an `ObservableCollection`. Whenever the combobox is modified to a specific value, the source of the button's content's image should change, but thats not happening.
How could i achieve that?
This is the part of the eventhandler responsible for the value change:

```
                ....
                if (status is ok)
                {
                    ((PlayerStartup)s).TokenSource = "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/pic.jpg";
                }
                .....
```

I would like to do this without any code in the view's code behind.

Properties and fields of `PlayerStartup`:

```
    private StartMenuViewModel.Status _status;
    private string _character;
    private string _name;
    private string _tokenSource;

    public StartMenuViewModel.Status Status { get { return _status; } set { _status = value; OnStatusChanged(); } }
    public string Character { get { return _character; } set { _character = value; OnCharacterChanged(); } }
    public string TokenSource { get { return _tokenSource; } set { _tokenSource = value; } }
```

Comment: please, include in you question code for `PlayerStartup.TokenSource` property. it can be the key to solve the issue

Comment: The Source should be bound to an Image. Not to the image path.This is a common mistake done. Please check.

Comment: @NorbertKovacs, `TokenSource ` doesn't notify when changes. `PlayerStartup` has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise event when `TokenSource ` was modified

Comment: @ASh I have already tried that, but didn't work. Now I tried it again and it did. Must have misspelled something, lol. Thanks! :)